# AngularJS/bootstrap typeahead not working with dynamic json returned from $http.get call

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

I have a web page with code like this:

```
<input type="text"
       class="form-control"
       ng-model="asynchSelected"
       typeahead="e as e.employee.fullName for e in searchEmployees($viewValue)">
```

searchEmployees returns json fetched from a Web API service using $http.get().  The returned json looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "employee": {
            "id": 0,
            "fullName": "Scott Nelson"
        }
    },
    {
        "employee": {
            "id": 0,
            "fullName": "Stacy Tester"
        }
    },
    {
        "employee": {
            "id": 0, "fullName": "Suzy Schmoozy" 
        }
    }
]
```

I would expect to see a dynamically-created dropdown list of employee names when typing into the textbox, but I get nothing...except on the browser debugger console I see this error:

```
TypeError: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference
```

I think I have something wrong with the expression I'm using in the typeahead, but I can't seem to find a good example of using a complex json object fetched from a web service with the typeahead control.

Strangely, if I hard-code the json in a variable called "employees", instead of trying to use $http.get() to return it, using code like this:

```
<input type="text"
       class="form-control"
       ng-model="selected"
       typeahead="e as e.employee.fullName for e in employees | filter:$viewValue">
```

it correctly displays the typeahead list...??
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: same exact issue....no errors. Tried to dropdown to simple strings, but still no go from http